# Convert date format in android?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm working on calender date picker. I am getting dates in format `2013/7/7`, but I want the format to be `2013/07/07`

Code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  
{

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,  cyear, cmonth, cday);
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListene = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
    {
        // onDateSet method
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date_selected = String.valueOf(year)+" /"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);

        dob.setText(date_selected);

    }
};
```

Comment: check the documentation of `SimpleDateFormatter.format()` and `SimpleDateFormatter.parse()` method

Comment: I have created a simple method to do this. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042733/4531507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String strDate="2013/7/7";
                String[] strsplit=strDate.split("/");
                int year=Integer.parseInt(strsplit[0]);
                int month=Integer.parseInt(strsplit[1]);
                int day=Integer.parseInt(strsplit[2]);

                if((month)<=9)
                    strDate+="0";
                strDate+=(month )+"/";
                if(day<=9)
                    strDate+="0";
                strDate+=(day)+"/";
                strDate+=(year);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date_selected);
```

Comment: `"yyyy/MM/dd"`, that's the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Use date formater

```
    String date="2013/7/7";
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    System.out.println(df.format(df.parse(date)));
```

Comment: mm means  minute in hour, MM= month in year.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing things the hard way. Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can have an easier to write, read and maintain code. Try not to re-invent the wheel.

Sample code will be something like this:

```
String date_string = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(original_date);
```

And of course you can re-use the instance of the `SimpleDateFormat` if you need to perform the operation more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
    //Calender Variables
int mYear;
int mDay;
int mHour;
int mMinute;
c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
TextView d = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
d.setText("Date: " + mDay+" / "+mMonth + " / "+mYear+" ");
t.setText("Time: " + mHour+" : "+mMinute);
date = d.getText().toString();
time = t.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format the date as you want by using `SimpleDateFormat` like this :

```
String format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
try {
      Date date = sdf.parse("12/31/2013"); // this date is in format MM/dd/yyyy and it will formatted to the format yyyy/MM/dd ( 2013/12/31 )
      System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // formatting
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); // this will format the current date to the format yyyy/MM/dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Calendar instance into DatePickerDialog, then use SimpleDateFormat to format as required.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListene = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
// onDateSet method
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, Calendar cal) {
    dob.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(cal.getTime()));
}
};
```